# Como recibir notificaciones que fueron enviadas a un topic antes de la subscripcion a este mismo

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que deben recibirse notificaciones solo al estar en un lugar de momento para simularlo uso un botón que al presionarlo se subscribe a un `topic` a al volverlo a presionar de de-subscribe.

El problema es que cuando esta de-suscrito y envió notificaciones y me vuelvo a presionar el botón la aplicación debería recibir las notificaciones que se enviaron igual que lo hace cuando se enviar al estar apagado el dispositivo y al prenderlo se reciben estas.

Comment: Bienvenido..Juan..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, puedes agregar el código por ejemplo, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desgraciadamente no es posible lo que comentas Juan.

Cuando te suscribes, puedes recibir notificaciones.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

Cuando de de-suscribes, a partir de este momento no puedes recibir notificaciones.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic()
```

Si no estas suscrito a un tema (topic) y enviaste notificaciones, estas no pueden ser recibidas a menos que ocurra un retraso en el envío por parte de los servidores de Google, pero las recibirías después de suscribirte.

Pero en realidad, **las notificaciones no se pueden recibir si no estas suscrito  a un tema y no se acumulan esperando te vuelvas a suscribir a el tema usando para el envió de notificaciones.**

---

> la aplicación debería recibir las notificaciones que se enviaron igual
>   que lo hace cuando se enviar al estar apagado el dispositivo y al
>   prenderlo se reciben estas.

**La diferencia aquí es que Google sabe que hay un dispositivo que esta en espera de recibir notificaciones, el cual no esta de-suscrito.**